# emacs tmp file created by previous OS can not be deleted in new OS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, emacs

I have installed a VirtualBox with ubuntu20.04 and add a share folder from windows11 host.

Then I use emacs and it create a tmp file:

```
$ ls -lah scripts2/org/.#drawer.org 

-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 30 Mar  7 11:52 scripts2/org/.#drawer.org
```

Maybe I do not close emacs then shutdown ubuntu, the tmp file not being deleted.

Now I deleted the ubuntu 20.04 VM and installed ubuntu 22.04, mount the share folder.

I found when I run sudo command to delete that tmp file, it says no permission:

```
$ sudo rm scripts2/org/.#drawer.org 
rm: cannot remove 'scripts2/org/.#drawer.org': Operation not permitted
```

I do it in windows11 host as well, no permission to delete it.

Any way I can remove this file?